# Pass select result as parameter of stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, parameters

I have a T-SQL stored procedure with the following parameters

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveData]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @UserID varchar(50),
    @ServiceID varchar(50),
    @param1 varchar(50),
    @param2 varchar(50),
    @endDate datetime
AS BEGIN
    . 
    .
    -- my code --
```

I want know if it is possible to pass a result of `select` as parameter:

```
    exec SaveDate (SELECT player.UserID,player.ServiceID, 'no','no',GETDATE()
           FROM player)
```

I tried something like this, but it does not work.

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: make procedure with a select statment, and smack SaveData with each cursor change. That would be easyest way. But take note, cursor is preformance killer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SELECT query you wrote in your example would probably bring back multiple rows (your SELECT does not feature a WHERE clause or a TOP(n)). If your intention is to be able to have your procedure engage a "tabular" set of parameters, from SQL Server 2008, you are able to use table valued parameters.

This involves creating a user defined table table and will almost undoubtedly mean adjusting the logic inside the stored procedure.

Hope this helps :)

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(SQL.100).aspx
for more information.

Answer (score 20):

1.One way is:
  
a) Declare your variables 
  
b) Assign values to them with a single select statement
  
c) Execute the procedure passing the local variables
  
d) Execute the following in a loop using WHILE or CURSOR in order to apply this for all rows in TABLE1

```
DECLARE @param1 <DATATYPE>, @param2 <DATATYPE>, ...

SELECT TOP 1 @param1 = col1,    @param2 = col2, ...
FROM TABLE1
WHERE <where_clause>

EXEC SaveDate @param1, @param2, ...
```

2.Other way is to define your own table type, fill it, and pass it to procedure. However this requires changing a little bit your stored procedure (in params list your custom type should be followed by `READONLY`):

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TYPENAME] AS TABLE(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    ...
)
GO

DECLARE @myTypeVar TYPENAME;

INSERT @myTypeVar
SELECT col1, col2, ...
FROM TABLE1

EXEC SaveData @myTypeVar
```

Comment: Would approach 1 execute for every row in the select query from OP? I don't think it does

Comment: @ShekharReddy, you are right, it won't. It should be looped using WHILE or CURSOR. Fixed in the answer.